# Conditional render if else props

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react world. So this is may be a silly question 
I am trying to do something similar to this https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator but instead of display the strings I want to display properties value

Something like this:

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      The user is <b>{isLoggedIn ? {prop1} : {prop2}}</b> logged in.
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I do that I get an error. But I can see the value of {prop1} and {prop2} if I put them outside of the if clause.

What other ways I could do something like this?
Have two returns would be ugly in my optinion because I would have some duplicated code when only what I want is to display some diffrerent string

EDIT: The error message is this

> react-dom.development.js:14793 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it. The error is react-dom.development.js:14793 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: try logging the prop1 to console and check

Comment: use `this.props.prop1` and `this.props.prop2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends on what type prop1 & prop2 are but try:

```
render() {
      const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
      return (
        <div>
          The user is <b>{isLoggedIn ? prop1 : prop2}</b> logged in.
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that prop1 and prop2 are strings (or numbers) you could do:

```js
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      The user is <b>{isLoggedIn ? prop1 : prop2}</b> logged in.
    </div>
  );
}
```

if they are them-self functions returning React elements :

```js
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      The user is <b>{isLoggedIn ? prop1() : prop2()}</b> logged in.
    </div>
  );
}
```

What you did is to render a javascript object do the dom as is

Answer (score 2):

When you use `{}` in your jsx code, you say react that it's a javascript code, and when you use `{}` inside `{}` you try to make an object. And as @Jerome replied you just need to remove the curly brackets. `{isLoggedIn ? prop1 : prop2}`. Also you can use `jsx` code inside `{}`, for example: `{isLoading ? <Loading/> : <MainBlock/>}`.